# Add keyframe for position of an Image strip with python

Tags: python, video-sequence-editor, keyframes

I want to add keyframe for position of an Image strip with python in video sequence editor.

[image]

I set the value like this:

```
 strip = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all[f"{Name}.png"]
 strip.transform.offset_y = -442.5
 strip.transform.offset_x = 820
```

And I want to insert a keyframe at frame 1.

```
strip.keyframe_insert(data_path="transform.offset_x", frame=1)
```

I can't figure out what data_path to use I tried 'transform.offset_x', 'transform' and many more but it either does not exist or "is not animatable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bpy

strip = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all[0]
strip.transform.offset_y = -5
strip.transform.keyframe_insert(data_path="offset_y", frame=1)
```

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you. I hate programming :D